# jQuery scroll to anchor with offset from external page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few anchors on a page. To navigate to them from the page itself, I am using a basic jQuery function, the main point being the offset:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('a[href^="http://website.org/visit-us#anchor1"]').on('click',function (e) { 

e.preventDefault();
var target = this.hash; 
var $target = jQuery(target); 
jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 250},#
900, 
'swing',function () {
window.location.hash = target - 240 ;
});

});
});
```

The issue is when I use the link from other pages, if the code is loaded it does not redirect to the link. If the code is not loaded, it passes the anchor link.

How can I modify the function to load it on the other pages so the offset would work?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're trying to link from page B back to this page A, and on document load, scroll to a specific target identified from the hash that's part of the link on page B?

Comment: @SetSailMedia, yes. Page A has the anchors. Page B has the links - when clicked, they should lead to Page A anchor - the offset

Answer (score 6):

In that case, firing a similar function like you've already written should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

// run on DOM ready

// grab target from URL hash (i.e. www.mysite.com/page-a.html#target-name)
var target = window.location.hash;

// only try to scroll to offset if target has been set in location hash
if ( target != '' ){
    var $target = jQuery(target); 
    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 250},
    900, 
    'swing',function () {
    window.location.hash = target - 240 ;
    });
}

});
```

Then on page B:

```
<a href="page-a.html#target-name">Link to #target-name on page A</A>
```